# Trimming the result of jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a page that takes an article from the article page but I want to only display some of the article, like the first 100 words.

So far my page loads the article successfully using this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#startOfArticle').load('article.html #officialArticle');
});
```

This is now loaded into the paragraph `<p id="startOfArticle></p>` but then I go to trim everything inside this paragraph using:

```
var shortened = $("#startOfArticle").text()
    .trim()
    .substring(0, 100)
    .split(" ")
    .slice(0, -1)
    .join(" ") + "...";
$('#startOfArticle').text(shortened+ '<a href="read">read more</a>')
```

but this is not trimming the article, any advice?

Comment: Are you trimming in a callback of load?

Comment: So, what *is* it doing instead?

Comment: Side note: this is trimming to 100 characters rather than 100 words.

Comment: @scrowler that's not a side note, that's something OP should have stated.

Comment: @scrowler sorry yes, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a pot shot of that you are calling trim before load has completed. You need to trim in the callback result. Something like

```
$(function(){
    $('#startOfArticle').load('article.html #officialArticle', function(data){
       var shortened = data
       .trim()
       .substring(0, 100)
       .split(" ")
       .slice(0, -1)
       .join(" ") + "...";
    $('#startOfArticle').text(shortened+ '<a href="read">read more</a>')});
});
```

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the edit - any idea of there alternatives to 4 spaces to code format? My phone wouldn't let me prefix with loads of white space

Comment: No.  This place requires spaces for indent.  It will use tabs, but not very well - spaces are the recommended indent.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, will follow up on meta to try and find a solution

Comment: @Ian I have tried to use this but now the result is just the first 100 characters of the HTML in article.html and when going to write '<a href="read">read more</a> it is writing this as code not as an actual link. (btw bare in mind I am very very new to JQuery and stackoverflow)

Comment: @user3743076: Firstly I'd suggest reading the jQuery docs and brushing up a little first, the StackOverflow community like people who try and help themselves. With your question however the `href="read"` doesn't really go anywhere. I guess you have additional code around this. What I'd do is if I've answered your question so far, mark this as the answer and ask a new question about the extra bit of behavior.

Comment: @ian thanks, I will, and yes I know, the code written is not even the actual code, it is just addapted to try to show the core problem.

Comment: @ian i will use your adivice, and thanks for your help

Comment: @user3743076: If my answer helped please feel free to accept it as the answer by checking the tick symbol. On StackOverflow we try to keep small concise questions so they're applicable to other users. So often it's better to ask more smaller questions than a few larger ones.

Answer (score 0):

To have an opportunity to manipulate the response, use jQuery .get, .post, or .load functions:

jQuery .load function example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#startOfArticle').load('article.html', function(data) {
        $('#startOfArticle').append($.parseHTML(data)).find('#officialArticle').each(function() {
            $('#startOfArticle').html($(this).text()
                .trim()
                .split(' ')
                .slice(0, 99)
                .join(' ') + '...<a href="read">read more</a>'
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use `.get()` instead of `.load()`?

Comment: You're missing the part that he's loading the `#officialArticle` element from that document, not the whole document.

Comment: Ah, ya, so he wants to get a portion of the article.html page. Hmmmm.